# Как сделать плавную останову персонажа на Unity2D

Tags: c#, unity3d

только недавно начал работать с unity. Начал создание 2D платформера с написания и разборов скриптов других людей для перемещения персонажа. 
Проблема в том, что персонаж не останавливает после двежения за `walkCooldown`, а делает это хаотично. Насколько понимаю проблема в методе `update`. Подскажите в чём проблема, зарание спасибо за помошь!

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{


    [Header("Speeds")]
    public float WalkSpeed = 60;
    public float JumpForce = 200;

    public BoxCollider2D boxColliderNormal;
    public BoxCollider2D boxColliderCrutch;



    private MoveState _moveState = MoveState.Idle;
    private DirectionState _directionState = DirectionState.Right;
    private Transform _transform;
    private Rigidbody2D _rigidbody;
    private Animator _animatorController;
    private float _walkTime = 0, _walkCooldown = 0.2f;

    private void BoxOnNormal()
    {
        boxColliderNormal.enabled = true;
        boxColliderCrutch.enabled = false;
    }

    private void BoxOffNormal()
    {
        boxColliderNormal.enabled = false;
        boxColliderCrutch.enabled = true;
    }


    public void MoveRight()
    {
        if (_moveState != MoveState.Jump &(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S)==false) )
        {
            BoxOnNormal();
            _moveState = MoveState.Walk;
            if (_directionState == DirectionState.Left)
            {
                _transform.localScale = new Vector3(-_transform.localScale.x, _transform.localScale.y, _transform.localScale.z);
                _directionState = DirectionState.Right;
            }
            _walkTime = _walkCooldown;
            _animatorController.Play("Walk");
        }
    }

    public void MoveLeft()
    {
        if (_moveState != MoveState.Jump & (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S) == false))
        {
            BoxOnNormal();
            _moveState = MoveState.Walk;
            if (_directionState == DirectionState.Right)
            {
                _transform.localScale = new Vector3(-_transform.localScale.x, _transform.localScale.y, _transform.localScale.z);
                _directionState = DirectionState.Left;
            }
            _walkTime = _walkCooldown;
            _animatorController.Play("Walk");
        }
    }

    public void Crutch()
    {
        if (_moveState != MoveState.Jump)
        {
            BoxOffNormal();
            _moveState = MoveState.Crutch;
            _animatorController.Play("Crutch");
                _walkTime = 0.07f;


        }
    }

        public void Jump()
    {
        if (_moveState != MoveState.Jump)
        {
            BoxOnNormal();
            _rigidbody.velocity += (Vector2.up * JumpForce * Time.deltaTime);
                _moveState = MoveState.Jump;
            _animatorController.Play("Jump");
        }
    }

    private void Idle()
    {
        _moveState = MoveState.Idle;
        _animatorController.Play("Idle");
    }

    private void Start()
    {
        _transform = GetComponent<Transform>();
        _rigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        _animatorController = GetComponent<Animator>();
        _directionState = transform.localScale.x > 0 ? DirectionState.Right : DirectionState.Left;
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (_moveState == MoveState.Jump)
        {
            if (_rigidbody.velocity == Vector2.zero)
            {
                Idle();
            }
        }
        else if (_moveState == MoveState.Walk)
        {
            _rigidbody.velocity = (_directionState == DirectionState.Right ? Vector2.right : -Vector2.right)
                                    * WalkSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
            _walkTime -= Time.deltaTime;
            if (_walkTime <= 0)
            {
                Idle();
            }
        }
         else if (_moveState == MoveState.Crutch)
        {
            _walkTime -= Time.deltaTime;
            if (_walkTime <= 0)
            {
                Idle();
            }
        }
    }

    enum DirectionState
    {
        Right,
        Left
    }

    enum MoveState
    {
        Idle,
        Walk,
        Jump,
        Crutch
    }
}
```

Comment: 2d игра... у вас движение по тайлам? что за `_walkTime`? что за `Crutch`? Закомментируйте по людски!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пример

```
enum kMove { None, Right, Left, }
private kMove _moveStatus;
private float _moveSpeed = 10f;
private float _decreaseFactor = 2f; // множитель погашения скорости
private float _increaseFactor = 3f; // множитель набора скорости
private Rigidbody2D _body;

void Update () {
    UpdateMove();    
}

void UpdateMove () {
    switch (_moveStatus) {
        case: kMove.None { UpdateMoveNone (); } break;
        case: kMove.Right { UpdateMoveRight (); } break;
        case: kMove.Left { UpdateMoveLeft (); } break;
    }
}

void UpdateMoveNone () {
    if (_body.velocity.x != 0) {
        float Decrease = _moveSpeed*Time.deltaTime*_decreaseFactor*-Mathf.Sign(_body.velocity.x);
        if (Mathf.Abs(Decrease) < Mathf.Abs(_body.velocity.x))
            _body.velocity += new Vector2(Decrease , 0); // Погашение скорости
        else
            _body.velocity = new Vector2(0, _body.velocity.y); // Скорость погашена
    }
}

void UpdateMoveRight () {
    if (_body.velocity.x < _moveSpeed) {
        _body.velocity += new Vector2(_moveSpeed, 0)*Time.deltaTime*_increaseFactor; // набор скорости
        if (_body.velocity.x > _moveSpeed) // проверка на перебор скорости
            _body.velocity = new Vector2(_moveSpeed), _body.velocity.y); // ограничение скорости
    }
}

void UpdateMoveLeft () {
    if (_body.velocity.x > -_moveSpeed) {
        _body.velocity += new Vector2(-_moveSpeed, 0)*Time.deltaTime*_increaseFactor; // набор скорости
        if (_body.velocity.x < -_moveSpeed) // проверка на перебор скорости
            _body.velocity = new Vector2(-_moveSpeed, _body.velocity.y); // ограничение скорости
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, извиняюсь ,что не смог отреагировать вовремя!